# Using external copied data as the sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I get data segmented into files by individual. I download the files and copy the individual's name. I want to create a macro that makes the sheet name what the copied individual's name is and after formatting it export the sheet to a PDF that is named what the sheet name is.

I've created the macro for the formatting already, just having trouble with the copied name part.

Comment: Please share what you already have.

Comment: the `Worksheet.Name` property is what you need to assign to, e.g., assuming a worksheet variable `ws`, then: `ws.Name = "copied value"`. Note that there are some limitations on the length of names, and also certain characters are not allowed in sheet names.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.